# Android contentResolver query with MediaStore returns empty cursor

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to get all the images on the device, for now my code is:

```kotlin
val imageProjection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
)

val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    imageProjection,
    null,
    null,
    "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED} DESC"
)

cursor?.use {
    val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    val nameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
    val sizeColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE)
    val dateColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN)
    while (it.moveToNext()) {
        val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
        val name = it.getString(nameColumn)
        val size = it.getString(sizeColumn)
        val date = it.getString(dateColumn)
        Log.d("IMAGE", "$id $name $size $date")
    }
}
```

The query does give me a Cursor, but the Cursor appears to be empty as the code never enter the while.

I've checked that i have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, and i do have it, but it still doesn't work, i also tried using `MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` as the query uri, but that didn't change anything, the result is always an empty cursor.

Can someone give me an hint on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: at a guess I would say your query fails because of the sort clause "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED} DESC. this should imho be something along the lines " BY "+MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED . Note the spaces before and after in the BY string

Comment: That's possible, I'll try, but if I remember well I also tried removing the sort parameter and passing null and it still didn't work

Comment: I have Razorsql on my pc with a copy of the Media database which you can get through the Androd Studio Device Explorer. Next step is the generate an sql error by adding a non-existing column name. Run the query in android and using the stacktrace output, I reconstruct the sql query in Razorsql and identify the error and fix  Works perfectly!! You should already have an sql error in your stacktrace though